# Fancybox Download Image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, href

I am trying to make a download button for the image you're currently viewing in Fancybox.
I thought it would be a easy thing to do because the url is already stored in the `<img>` tag so I thought I could just re-use that for the link.

I even tried to find the `<img>`'s `src` in fancybox and then `.append` it to the `href` of the link *(`<a>` tag)*. I just lack the jQuery skills to get it done.

To `fancybox.js` I've added the `<a>` tag:

```
<img class="fancybox-image" src="image.jpeg" alt="" />
<a href="" class="test">Download</a>
```

I tried to copy-and-paste the *`image.jpeg`* like so but that didn't work:

```
var href = $('.fancybox-image').attr('href');
$('a.test').attr('href', href );
```

Comment: Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Comment: I am sorry first posts here i cant get the code to show properly -.-

Comment: I edited the post for you, use 4 spaces to intend the code in the future. Feel free to revert any changes you want if I misunderstood any part of the question. See [the Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Comment: Tyvm :) you got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### The jQuery way
>
> This answer shows how to accomplish this using standard jQuery methods, correcting the code OP has given. **See also [Janis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18274789/1935077)** to see how this can be done using Fancybox.

The code you posted here doesn't work because there is no `href` attribute in the `<img>` tag. You should use the `src` attribute instead:

```
var href = $('.fancybox-image').attr('src');
$('a.test').attr('href', href );
```

However, this will work only if there is only one image with class `.fancybox-image`. If you have multiple images in your gallery, use the following approach instead:

```
$('.fancybox-image').each(function (){
    var href = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).next("a").attr("href", href);
});
```

#### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUdjj/2)

Comment: Thx changed your code a bit and got it working:

$('.fancybox-inner').each(function (){
    var href = $('.fancybox-image').attr('src');
    $(this).children("a").attr("href", href); 
});<br />
.next would be img again.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but you can add download link inside title area of fancyBox - http://jsfiddle.net/zAe6Z/

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        this.title = '<a href="' + this.href + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You make it look easy. I've seriously been looking for that a long time.