# How to add a download button on Fancybox?

Tags: php, fancybox, fancybox-3

I would like to add a download link in my Fancybox. I'm new in programming and I can't seem to figure out what code to use and where to put it. Thank you in advance.

I'm using FancyBox v3.2.10.

Here's the code:

```
<?php  $directory = "images/"; ?>
    <?php $dir = glob ($directory . "*.{jpg,png,gif,JPG}",GLOB_BRACE) ?>

    <?php foreach ($dir as $key => $value): ?>

        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="<?php echo $value; ?>" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $value; ?>" alt="" />
            </a>

        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273091/fancybox-download-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  buttons : [
    'download',
    'thumbs',
    'close'
  ]
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXjGQB